# Updating all rows + WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to update all users who have '300000' gold in their bank and set them to '15000'
I tried running this script:

```
<?php
      $db_handle = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pass", "db") or die("|-1");
      if($db_handle) 
      $value = '15000';
      mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE playerdata SET Bank='$value' WHERE Bank = '300000'");


?>
```

I couldn't find alot of the internet regarding updating all rows with a WHERE statement.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So how is this not working for you? the update would change ALL records where the bank field is 300000.

Comment: [Sure?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: The query looks fine - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the type of the column isn't a string?  Is it some numeric type?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax glitches:

```
  if($db_handle) 
  $value = '15000';
```

You have no `{}` on your if(), so this code is being executed as:

```
$db_handle = ...
if ($db_handle) {
   $value = '15000';
}
mysqli_query(...);
```

Since you're not properly checking for a connection failure, or doing anything if a failure DID occur, you're blindly running a query on a connection which may not exist. The code should be

```
 $db_handle = mysqli_connect(...);
 if (!$db_handle) {
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 mysqli_query($db_handle, "query goes here") or die(mysqli_error($db_handle));
```

Never **EVER** assume your query succeeds. There's exactly **ONE** way for it to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.